# Swift Firebase Crash upon file upload request

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a swift observable object file that I am working on making and every time I call the object the program crashes, I don't have any understanding to why it is crashing. I have gone over firebase api documentation. I have zero errors being reported also, here is the code.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

enum Action {
    case Upload
    case Download
}

enum TransferType {
    case URL(Address: String)
    case Firebase(Collection: String, DocumentID: String)
}

enum ModelType {
    
    //MARK: - #1
    //Different Types of Model Types that will be uploaded and downloaded
    case ActiveJobsite
    case UserData
}

class JsonRequest: ObservableObject {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var URL: String?
    
    
    //MARK: - #2
    //Temporary optionals for each custom model type
    
    @Published var ActiveJobsite: [ActiveJob]?
    
    @Published var UserData: UsersData?
    
    
    
    //Status of Upload-Download Request
    
    @Published var Completed: Bool = false
    
    @Published var Fetching: Bool = false
    
    @Published var CollectionID: String?
    
    @Published var DocumentID: String?
    
    
    func JsonRequest(TransferType: TransferType, ModelType: ModelType, Action: Action) {
        if Action == .Download {
            DownloadJson()
        } else
        if Action == .Upload {
            UploadJson(ModelType: ModelType, TransferType: TransferType)
        } else {
            //Errpr
        }
        
    }
        
    func DownloadJson(){
        
        
        
  //      db.addDocument(data: <#T##[String : Any]#>)
    }
    
    func UploadJson(ModelType: ModelType, TransferType: TransferType) {
        
        let JsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        JsonEncoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
                // case Firebase
                switch TransferType {
                        
                    case .Firebase(let Collection, let DocumentID):
                    //Test If Document Exsists
//MARK: - #3
//Make a encoder for Each Model Type
                    
                    //ActiveJob Encoder
                        if ModelType == .ActiveJobsite {
                            
                            if let Jobsite = self.ActiveJobsite {
                                do {
                                    let encodedData = try JsonEncoder.encode(Jobsite)
                                    FirebaseUpload(Collection: Collection, DocumentId: DocumentID, Data: encodedData)
                                } catch {
                                    //error
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    
                     //UserData Encoder
                    
                        if ModelType == .UserData {
                            
                            if let UserData = self.UserData {
                                do {
                                    let encodedData = try JsonEncoder.encode(UserData)
                                    FirebaseUpload(Collection: Collection, DocumentId: DocumentID, Data: encodedData)
                                } catch {
                                    //error
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    
                    case .URL(let address):
                        UploadError(Address: address)
                    }

        
        
    }

    func FirebaseUpload(Collection: String, DocumentId: String, Data: Data) {
        //Test If Document Exsists
        let File = db.collection("\(Collection)").document("\(DocumentId)")
            
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data, options: []) as? [String : Any] {
                    
                    File.setData(json)
                } else {
                    //Error
                    print("errorMsg")
                }
            } catch {
                print("errorMsg")
            }
        }

    func UploadError(Address: String) {
        print("Cant Upload to URL: \(Address)")
        }
}
```

I was expecting it to create a new collection and document in firebase upon being called

Comment: Totally off topic but generally speaking when writing code, variables you define start with a lowercase character. Upper case is generally used for Struct, Class and Enum definitions. Nothing to do with the question but it makes the code more readable and standardized.

Comment: Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so please include what you did, what line crashed and what the expected result was of that line.

Comment: Also, what does `UserData` resolve to?